# Custom StorageManager using GrapesJs API Storage Manager

Tags: grapesjs

I am new in GrapesJs & Trying to achieve the following:

I'm trying to implement a custom Storage Manager using [Storage API of GrapesJs](https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/storage_manager.html#storagemanager)

I'm trying to get/set the data from/to localStorage (i.e. ResponseFromLocalStorage).

Below is my code:

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
    container: '#gjs',
    fromElement: true,
    height: '500px',
    width: 'auto',
    storageManager: { 
        type: 'jekyllLocalStore'
    }
});

//Custom Storage
var storeMan=editor.StorageManager;
//set Config
storeMan.setAutosave=true;
storeMan.setStepsBeforeSave=1;

//Now Add Custom Storage Manager
storeMan.add('jekyllLocalStore', {
    load: function(ResponseFromLocalStorage, clb1) {
          var res = {};
          $.each(ResponseFromLocalStorage,function(key,val){
            console.log(key+'--->'+val);
            if(val) res[key] = val;
          });
          clb1(res); // might be called inside some async method
    },
    store: function(ResponseFromLocalStorage, clb2) {
           localStorage.setItem("wholeRes123",JSON.stringify(ResponseFromLocalStorage));
           clb2(); // might be called inside some async method
    }
});
```

While the code executes, the localStorage item named **wholeRes123** is created successfully, with the data from **ResponseFromLocalStorage**, but at the time of storing the changes are not getting updated in **wholeRes123**.

My understanding is, if **autoSave** is set **true**, then the storing should begin when the editing is done, and then the **store:** should execute the code.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me out on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your code may be saving, but it isnt loading. Try adding autoload to true, or try calling it after you save